# In which version of c++ was comma separated multi-line if statement introduced and are there any downsides of using it?

Tags: c++, syntax

I came across this line of code yesterday:

```
if(flag[j] == 0) q.push(j), flag[j]=1, val[j]=0, parent[j]=p;
```

I didn't know we could write multi-line if statement like this and couldn't find any article related to this.
Are there any downsides of using it?

Comment: That's not a new thing. `if(init-statement; condition)` is new since c++17 though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I guess that's what they're asking...

Comment: @AStopher I don't think so. My comment is not even close to the same thing but was the first new thing in `if`'s that I could think of. OP:s `if` has been valid (but ridiculous) since day 1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It exists starting from the C birth [Built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` statements apply to a single statement. Normally you would make multiple statement into a single statement using braces.

In your example the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) is being used instead. I can't think of any good reason to do this, if you need to use multiple expressions use braces. Using commas is harder to read and will confuse non-c++ experts (and even some experts, the comma operator isn't a widely used part of the language).

Comment: Single statement, not single expression.

Comment: To put some extra light on how hard it is to read: `return q.push(j), flag[j]=1, val[j]=0, parent[j]=p;` would also be valid if the function was to return `p` (and `parent`s copy assignment operator behaves normally).